# Is there a database containing sequences of human cell lines?

Tags: dna-sequencing

I'm looking for the whole genome sequences of several human cell lines, e.g., A549 or Ea.hy.926. Is there a database specifically dedicated to human cell lines?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://cancer.sanger.ac.uk/cancergenome/projects/cell_lines/

Comment: Thank you, I found this one already. Is this the only one?

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @kmm (http://cancer.sanger.ac.uk/cancergenome/projects/cell_lines/) is an excellent database. Alternatively you can look at the broad institute page (http://www.broadinstitute.org/software/cprg/?q=data-resource) in the cancer cell line encyclopedia section, then go to the browse tab and select the cell line for a very comprehensive list of cell lines.